# How to add new field to 'catalog_product_option' table using Schema Patch?

Tags: magento2.3, custom-options, magento2.4, patch-data

I have created a custom option checkbox field, now on save, i have to update the value(0/1) to the table 'catalog_product_option' so that i can utilize this field on frontend.

[image]

**How can i achieve this using Schema Patch ?**

Answer (score 0):

Using following code, we can create :-

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2019 Magenest. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Setup\Patch\Schema;


use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class AddCrAllowedBrandAutoserachProductCustomOptionField implements SchemaPatchInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

     /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }


    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }


    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }


    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();


        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('catalog_product_option'),
            'cr_allowed_brand_autoserach',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'comment'  => 'Allowed Brand Autoserach',
            ]
        );


        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
}
```